# Delphi - AV error when using second form

Tags: forms, delphi, access-violation

I have a main form which uses the following code to create a sub-form, when a button is clicked. The form to be created (`frmNewMember`) has been removed from the auto-create forms list.

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnAddMemberClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  NewMemberForm: TForm;
begin
  NewMemberForm := TfrmNewMember.Create(Application);
  try
    NewMemberForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    NewMemberForm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The AV occurs when I try to use a component within a procedure which I have created within the form. For example:

```
procedure DoSomething;
begin
  frmNewMember.edtPostcode.Text := 'TEST';
end;
```

This would raise an AV with read error 000003BC. Is this occurring because I am trying to access an instance of `frmNewMember` which doesn't exist? I'm sure there's a simple answer to this, but I've searched all over the place and can't seem to get rid of the AV error.

Comment: Yes, it is because of that. You're (almost surely) accessing the automatically declared global form variable which refers to nil (that form is not auto-created). Better make method from your `DoSomething` procedure to that form class.

Comment: @TLama Thanks for the reply. How would I refer to the form which I have created from my main form? Would I need to pass the `NewMemberForm` variable over to my sub-form?

Comment: @PeterVonča I understand now. Thank's for your help. Something so simple, but I just didn't understand the logic behind it. `frmNewMember` replaced NewMemberForm and everything works fine.

Comment: That global form variable and relying on it is not a good idea. If I were you, I would delete that declaration to not mislead you anymore. Then I would make from your procedure a [`method of that form`](http://pastebin.com/Dc6hGh7k).

Comment: @Babah That's the wrong solution. Keep the local. Kill the global.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
frmNewMember
```

This is the global variable that the Delphi IDE (un)helpfully declared for you. You've never assigned it, and so it is still nil. Hence the access violation.

You've stopped using auto-create which is the right thing to do. The next step is to purge your code of these useless global variables. Once you've done that you cannot make this mistake again.

You'll still need to get the form reference into that function. But now you can pass it in as a parameter. Or make the function be a method of the form. That makes your code better too, so you keep on winning.

I think of this issue as *the curse of VB*. The global form variable was added to allow Delphi to mimic the behaviour of VB. We long since realised that VB sucked in that regard. But we are still left with these dreadful globals.

---

Asides:

- The local variable may as well be declared as TfrmNewMember.
- There is no point passing Application to the constructor since you manage the life with a try/finally. Pass nil instead.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, howeever, I'm having no luck implementing it. I've tried to do some research, but still no luck. Also, @TLama 's code would not allow me to se my procedure via a button click. Correct?

Comment: Your `DoSomething` is no good as it stands. You need to either pass it a form reference as a parameter, or make it a method of the form.